# AnyKey Keyboard Software?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I'm still using the old 124-key programmable [**AnyKey** keyboard from *Gateway 2000*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_AnyKey).
Do you know some tools or drivers for it?

Comment: For what OS do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [link text](http://www.howtogeek.com) site there is a [SharpKeys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) utility that allows to map any key to any other key.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [this website](http://www.freestuffandmoney.com/forsale/drivers.html)

It's got utility's called: Anykey34.exe or anykeyutility.exe, but they are aimed for DOS. I have no idea whether that kind of hardware is still supported.

Luckily for you a user of the keyboard posted how he uses it:

> My second keyboard is an old Gateway
>   AnyKey keyboard with it's own built-in
>   macro functions and onboard memory.
>   It's plugged into a regular PS2. I'm
>   using this as a controller or command
>   sequencer for Reaper.
>
> The Gateway AnyKey keyboard lets you
>   program a sequence of keystrokes into
>   any key; that sequence is then played
>   back when the key is pressed. Because
>   this functionality is self-contained
>   in the kb, **the computer needs no
>   awareness that the incoming sequence
>   is programmed** -- it just receives it
>   as regular input (though at a very
>   high speed) and responds accordingly.
>
> For example, I want to quickly toggle
>   the mute on all my vocal tracks. I
>   program a key on the AnyKey to send a
>   sequence that uses the SWS ReaConsole
>   command to do this:
>
> cm*vo*[ENTER]
>
> When I press this key, the sequence is
>   sent, which "manually" opens the
>   console [c], specifies the mute action
>   [m], specifies that it should apply to
>   all tracks with vo anywhere in their
>   name [*vo*], and then sends the Enter
>   key. It all happens in a fraction of a
>   second.
>
> I can program this into any key that I
>   want, eg, the F1 key, and use the F2
>   key to unmute all *vo* tracks, by
>   adding a hyphen in front of the same
>   command sequence.
>
> **Because the AnyKey kb's
>   programmability is self-contained, it
>   has no effect at all on my main
>   keyboard, whose F1 and F2 keys do what
>   they're supposed to do -- there is no
>   duplication *of those keys*.**
>
> Now, all of the regular keys on the
>   AnyKey kb can be programed in this
>   way, BUT -- and this is important and
>   the key to how this works -- all keys
>   that are NOT specifically programmed
>   will behave normally, and will be seen
>   by the OS as regular kb input. **In
>   other words, unprogrammed keys are
>   "duplicates" but keys that ARE
>   programmed are not.**
>
> As mentioned, the AnyKey's
>   programmability is entirely
>   self-contained, so even though Windows
>   sees a second duplicate keyboard, the
>   keyboard itself is capable of sending
>   out alternate sequences. The problem
>   with this is that the AnyKey is old,
>   and it's memory is limited and, sadly,
>   not as strong as it once was.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there is not description what the programs do and how they work.